# Ios dynamics crm mobile appllication ssl certificates

Tags: android, macos, ssl, mobile, dynamics-crm

all.

I am trying to set up MS Dynamics CRM 2016 moblie application on 2 devices: Android and IOs.
I have a deployment configuration ADFS + MS CRM, and It works correctly.

I made 3 certificates in openssl. My custom certification authority, and 2 child certificates, signed by this CA, all with private keys.

All certificates are installed on mobile devices.

I succeeded with setting mobile app on Android device - it started and connected to my server through ADFS.

But when I am installing my child sertificates on Apple device, I have the problem:
 1. I installed CA certificate on IOS device and it is verified.
 2. I tried to install my child certificates - but IOs showed me "the profile is not signed"
 3. I cannot even open web client by url at IOs device without certificate issue, at the same time I successfulle can open it from android browser or windows desktop.
 4. Finally I cannot connect MS Dynamics CRM Mobile application from IOs, because "the server doesn't have trusted SSL certificate"

What can be the problem? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.
With regards, Yuriy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved when I deployed Certification Authority role on my windows server and started to use certificates from this real CA.
To get to the reason of my previous problem - I need to compare two CA certificates.